# Using the splitAt in a regex reg_split to store them in the resulting array

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

Is there a way to use the splitAt in a regex preg_split, and store them in the resulting array, along with the results? For example:

```
$text = " did the great white eat the fishes ";
$text = preg_split("~( did | eat )~", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 

print_r($text);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => the great white [1] => the fishes )
```

**Want Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => the great white [1] => eat [2] => the fishes )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag to capture the delimiters being used in resulting array:

```
$text = " did the great white eat the fishes ";
$wrds='did|eat';

$arr = preg_split("~\h+($wrds)\h+~", preg_replace("/^\h*($wrds)\h+/", "" $text),
                  -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
print_r($arr);
```

Or else:

```
$arr = preg_split("~^\h+(?:$wrds)\h+|\h+($wrds)\h+~", $text, -1,
              PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
   [0] => the great white
   [1] => eat
   [2] => the fishes
)
```

Comment: But I don't want it to store splitAt with an empty index, and 'did' returned an empty index. So, I only want to the result to be Array ( [0] => the great white [1] => eat [2] => the fishes )

Comment: Because I only want to capture the delimiter that actually caused a split, and only the word 'eat' caused a split between the words 'the great white' and 'the fishes'. The word 'did' did not cause a split between any words.

Comment: You're mistaken on that. `did` indeed caused a split. Test with `"~ (done|eat) ~"` regex to see that `done` is not in output since `done` indeed wasn't used in split.

Comment: 'did' did caused a split between 'nullString' and 'the great white'. What I meant to say is that both strings between the split has to be NOT empty. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94364/discussion-between-jessica-and-anubhava).

Comment: ...but I just said that I DON'T want to capture the delimiter that doesn't cause a split between one or more empty strings. And the word 'did' does exactly that, and you're still containing it in the split. I only want the result to be: Array ( [0] => the great white [1] => eat [2] => the fishes ), and not 'DID the great white' ...ect.

Comment: The word 'did' and 'eat' has to be treated the same way. We don't know which word is which, because they're going to be user inputs. We only know that both words are 'verbs' and that they are to be used in a preg_split to separate the words.

Comment: Try; `$wrds='did|eat'; $arr = preg_split("~^\h+(?:$wrds)\h+|\h+($wrds)\h+~", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the 'did' or 'eat' delimiter only when it is in
the middle, you'd probably have to check the edge cases first:

```
^(?: did | eat )|(?: did | eat )$|( did | eat )
```

with these options `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`

In Perl there is no comparable `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = " did the great white eat the fishes ";
$array = preg_split("~( did | eat )~", $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); 
preg_match("~$array[0](.+?)$array[1]~", $text, $match);

$text1 = $array[0];
$text2 = $array[1];
$text3 = $match[1];

echo $text1."<br>".$text3."<br>".$text2;
```

**Result:**

```
the great white
eat 
the fishes
```

Comment: You're assuming each string will split in half. Not a very good assumption.